# JPA Connection to MySQL Throws "TOO MANY CONNECTION" Error

Tags: mysql, jpa, glassfish

i tries to connect to mysql database through the Application-Server Glassfish and JPA.

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="WEBSERVIE-EJB"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>AVS_TWO</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />          
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But if i trie that, the console of eclipse gives me the following error:

> Exception : Connection could not be allocated because: Data source
>   rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many
>   connections"
>
> Exception [EclipseLink-4019] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Exception
>   Description: Error while obtaining information about the database.
>   Refer to the nested exception for more details.   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.errorRetrieveDbMetadataThroughJDBCConnection(DatabaseException.java:368)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:225)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:734)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:681)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:395)
>     at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:484)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   No operations allowed after connection closed.    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1246)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1241)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:2946)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:2941)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.getMetaData(ConnectionHolder.java:357)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.getMetaData(ConnectionWrapper40.java:114)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:209)
>     ... 46 more Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from
>   the server was 26.046 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent
>   successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:988)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3552)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3452)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3893)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setSessionMaxRows(ConnectionImpl.java:5432)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1960)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.PreparedStatementWrapper40.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper40.java:642)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1002)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:641)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:281)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeNonCursor(DataReadQuery.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataReadQuery.java:152)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.execute(DataReadQuery.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3207)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1730)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.SchemaManager.checkTableExists(SchemaManager.java:477)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator.extendTables(TableCreator.java:431)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator.extendTablesAndConstraints(TableCreator.java:411)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator.extendTables(TableCreator.java:402)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.SchemaManager.extendDefaultTables(SchemaManager.java:1189)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.generateDefaultTables(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:108)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDLToDatabase(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:3937)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDL(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:3865)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDL(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:3765)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:724)
>     ... 43 more Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused
>   connection abort: recv failed     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:101)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:144)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:174)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3001)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3462)  ... 78
>   more
>
> 2016-08-03T13:09:47.479+0200|Schwerwiegend: Exception while deploying
>   the app [WEB] 2016-08-03T13:09:47.479+0200|Schwerwiegend: Exception
>   during lifecycle processing
>   org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Exception
>   [EclipseLink-4019] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Exception
>   Description: Error while obtaining information about the database.
>   Refer to the nested exception for more details.   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:762)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:395)
>     at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:484)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The "max_connections" in mysql is set to 600.
So that be enough.

Whats the problem?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database otherwise, such as through other JDBC based applications or tested the datasource within glassfish?  How have you created the "AVS_TWO" datasource?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use connection pool?
For eclipse link, you can take a look at [this](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_connection_pool.htm)  link

Answer (score 0):

I connect to glassfish with JTA. So i have configure a JDBC Connection Pool in Glassfish. If i trigger the 'Ping' Button in glassfish for testing the connection, it works.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

B.5.2.7 Too many connections

If you get a Too many connections error when you try to connect to the mysqld server, this means that all available connections are in use by other clients.

The number of connections permitted is controlled by the max_connections system variable. The default value is 151 to improve performance when MySQL is used with the Apache Web server. (Previously, the default was 100.) If you need to support more connections, you should set a larger value for this variable.